# My First PowerShell Project - How to manage interop between script files and neighboring modules?

Tags: powershell, directory-structure

## Preface

I expect this to be marked as duplicate, but there are so many answers spanning a decade of PowerShell history that I'm uncertain which answers pass muster and which are outdated. Please forgive me if such an answer is already here.

## Question

How should I structure the project? Once written, how do I import it? Ideally, these are going to be scripts I use frequently, but want to share with coworkers, so it should be compatible with Git, and/or able to be published out to a private Artifactory instance. I'm also interested in potentially making this a pre-compiled C# project, but that's an advanced topic that I didn't want to explore until I got some simple scripts working.

## Code Samples

What I have so far looks like this:

```
~/My Documents/PowerShell (as found in $Env:PSModulePath)
|   Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
|
\---Modules
    +---Docker
    |   |   Docker.psd1
    |   |
    |   +---classes
    |   |       DockerContainerHealth.ps1
    |   |       DockerContainerIsolation.ps1
    |   |       DockerContainerStatus.ps1
    |   |
    |   \---public
    |           Remove-DockerContainer.ps1
    |           Remove-DockerImage.ps1
    |
    +---FileSystem
    |   |   FileSystem.psd1
    |   |
    |   \---public
    |           Test-PathLike.ps1
    |
    +---Utilities
    |   |   Utilities.psd1
    |   |
    |   \---public
    |           Append-StringBuilder.ps1
    |
    \---WSL
        |   WSL.psd1
        |
        \---public
                Invoke-OpenPgp.ps1
```

### ~/My Documents/PowerShell/Modules/Docker/public/Remove-DockerContainer.ps1

```
function Remove-DockerContainer
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [System.String]$ContainerId,
    [System.String]$ContainerName,
    [System.String]$ContainerLabel,
    [System.Int32]$ContainerExitCode,
    [DockerContainerStatus]$ContainerStatus,
    [System.String]$ImageName,
    [System.String]$ImageId,
    [System.String]$BeforeContainerId,
    [System.String]$SinceContainerId,
    [System.String]$VolumeName,
    [System.String]$NetworkName,
    [System.String]$Port,
    [DockerContainerHealth]$ContainerHealth,
    [DockerContainerIsolation]$ContainerIsolation,
    [switch]$IsTask,
    [switch]$ShowStopped,
    [switch]$ShowLast,
    [System.Int32]$Limit
  )

  $args = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
  $args.Append('docker container ls -q')

  # Either shows last
  if($ShowLast) { $args.Append(' -l') }
  # Or list N most-recent
  elseif ($Limit -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -n $Limit") }

  if($ContainerId -ne $null) { $args.Append("-f id=$ContainerId") }
  if($ContainerName -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f name=$ContainerName") }
  if($ContainerLabel -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f label=$ContainerLabel") }
  if($ContainerExitCode -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f exited=$ContainerExitCode") }
  if($ContainerStatus -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f status=$([DockerContainerStatus].GetEnumName($ContainerStatus).ToLower())") }
  if($ImageName -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f ancestor=$ImageName") }
  if($ImageId -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f ancestor=$ImageId") }
  if($BeforeContainerId -ne $null) { $args.Append('f').Append("before=$BeforeContainerId") }
  if($SinceContainerId -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f since=$SinceContainerId") }
  if($VolumeName -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f volume=$VolumeName") }
  if($NetworkName -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f network=$NetworkName") }
  if($Port -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f expose=$Port") }
  if($ContainerHealth -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f health=$([DockerContainerHealth].GetEnumName($ContainerHealth).ToLower())")}
  if($ContainerIsolation -ne $null) { $args.Append(" -f isolation=$([DockerContainerIsolation].GetEnumName($ContainerIsolation).ToLower())") }
  if($IsTask) { $args.Append(' -f is-task=true') }

  if($ShowStopped -eq $false) { $ShowStopped = $ContainerExitCode -ne $null -or $ContainerStatus -ne $null }

  
  foreach($containerId in (Invoke-Expression "$args"))
  {
    docker wait "$containerId"
    docker container rm "$containerId"
  }
}
```

### ~/My Documents/PowerShell/Modules/Utilities/public/Append-StringBuilder.ps1

```
function Append-StringBuilder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [System.Text.StringBuilder]$Builder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [System.String]$Value
    )

    process
    {
        if($Value -ne $null -and $Value.Count -gt 0) { $Builder.Append($Value) }
        return $Builder
    }
}

function Aggregate-String
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [System.Text.StringBuilder]$Builder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [System.String]$Value
    )

    begin
    {
        if($Builder -eq $null) { $Builder = New-Item System.Text.StringBuilder }
    }

    process
    {
        $Builder | Append-StringBuilder $Value
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Append-StringBuilder
Export-ModuleMember -Function Aggregate-String
```

## Problem(s)

1. **How should I structure the project folder?** As the question says, this is my first PowerShell project. I'm familiar with the syntax, and have spent a ton of time reviewing the [PowerShell about* documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about?view=powershell-7.3). That said, it fails to discuss HOW modules should be structured. I found an [opinionated guide](https://github.com/questionmark/PowerShellTemplate) courtesy of a [Reddit thread on r/PowerShell](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b1xixn/powershell_project_structure_sample/), but the post is from 4 years ago, and the template project was archived last year which implies that some information might be out of date.
2. **How do I export classes and enums?** The documentation for PowerShell has a glaring omission on how to export classes and enums. In the PowerShellTemplate project, there is no explicit syntax for exporting an enum [as seen here](https://github.com/questionmark/PowerShellTemplate/blob/master/classes/10-ModuleFileType.ps1) but it's later referenced that the file name should be prefixed with a number to denote the order it is initialized for some PowerShell cmdlet `Optimize-Module` that I can't find documented anywhere.
3. **How do I import between modules, such as `Utilities` into `Docker`?** You may notice a common pattern in the provided sample of `Remove-DockerContainer`, which is why I wrote `Append-StringBuilder`. I'd like to import it, but similar to the lack of information from Microsoft on how to structure a project, there's little to no information on how to make a relative import. It says "When `<module-name>` is a path, the path can be fully qualified or relative. A relative path is resolved relative to the script that contains the using statement." This omits whether I should import the script `using module ../Utilities/Append-StringBuilder.ps1` or the module `using module ../Utilities` or the module manifest `../Utilities/Utilities.psd1`.

## Closing

Since I'm very new to PowerShell projects, any reference material would be greatly appreciated. I'm tired of writing one-off scripts and scrounging around for where I saved them, so I'm trying to get into a better habit of formalizing scripts for re-use. I've been doing this for Bash for a while, and would like to improve my experience on Windows.

Comment: In case anyone reading this wonders why I'd write this when the Docker CLI already exists, I found some facets unfriendly. For instance, I was struggling to get the Dockerfile right on a new project. Every time I tried to delete the image, it would inform me that there are containers using it. When I tried to delete the containers, it would inform me that they were still running. This prompted me to write a cmdlet that would delete the containers using an image, and in the process of deleting it would also wait for any running containers to stop.